# Spring data mongodb aggregation | custom sort based on the order of the enum attributes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data

I'm trying to sort a data set based on the order (ordinal) of the enum attributes. Let's say I have the following enum

```
public enum Status {
  IN_PROGRESS,
  RESOLVED,
  NEW
}
```

Based on the above I want my dataset to be sorted as NEW, IN_PROGRESS & RESOLVED order rather than the alphabetical order of the enum name.

I'm already using aggregation to perform some filtering. So now I need a way to achieve custom sorting with my aggregation

```
Aggregation.newAggregation(Case.class,
            match(filterCriteria),
            sort(generateCustomSort()),
            limit(limit),
            skip(skipCount)):
```

I know for a fact that with JPA we have the `@Enumerated` annotation & we can set it to use the ordinal of the enum to sort the data. Is there something similar in Spring data MongoDB? Or with a projections can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, since MongoDB doesn't allow sorting customization (B-tree stuff).

**Workaround:** add to your enums numbers, store the numbers in Mongodb documents and use them to order

```
public enum Status {
  IN_PROGRESS(2),
  RESOLVED(3),
  NEW(1);

  private int id;

  Status(int id){
      this.id = id;
  }
}
```